# Firebase AdMob is leaking my activity

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks, admob

I am using this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.0'
```

After adding a banner ad, my activity starts leaking but leakcanary gives me interesting analyze that I can't make any sense:

[image]

This is how I add the ad into my MainActivity:

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        initializeAds();
  }

 private void initializeAds() {
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.ad_app_id));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

  /** Called when leaving the activity */
    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
    }

    /** Called when returning to the activity */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.resume();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

It started to give me that leak after I add the AdView. What's keeping reference to my activity here? Do you have any idea?

Comment: This is 100% AdMob as I am also seeing this exact leak. When this leak was captured, one of the lines in catlog was: `LeakCanary: |   g = com.google.ads.afma.nano.h@854477824 (0x32ee4c00)`. I can't seem to find a solution though.

Comment: Welcome to the club! =)